# Why is the function either maximum or minimum when the constraint is tangential to the function contour?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Given a function $f(x,y)$ and a constraint $g(x,y)=c$, **Assuming** the fact that the function either maximum or minimum when the constraint is tangential to the function contour, I get why the gradients are proportional, namely $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ . But I don't understand in the first place why the function attains its critical points on the constraint only when they are tangential.

Comment: I think the intuitive explanation is that, if they weren’t tangent, then they would intersect, meaning that the constraint would cross over to other contours, so that “that” contour was not optimal.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "The method of Lagrange multipliers relies on the intuition that at a maximum, $f(x,y)$ cannot be increasing in the direction of any such neighboring point that also has $g(x,y)=c$. If it were, we could walk along $g(x,y)=c$ to get higher, meaning that the starting point wasn't actually the maximum. Viewed in this way, it is an exact analogue to testing if the derivative of an unconstrained function is $0$, that is, we are verifying that the directional derivative is $0$ in any relevant (viable) direction." Note this intuition is only sufficient for domains without boundaries.

Comment: If instead you were looking for a rigorous proof of this, you can readily find many on the internet already

Comment: @jnez71 No, I'm not looking for rigorous proof. That Wikipedia excerpt, what if there's a contour that exactly kisses the constraint at two points?

Comment: Then *both* of those "kissing" points will be candidates for the optimum. The Lagrange multiplier condition is necessary, not sufficient. The resulting equations can have multiple solutions and each one will require further testing (comparison or examination of the Hessian).

Comment: @jnez71 Cool, thanks man, Convert it to an answer I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier):

> "The method of Lagrange multipliers relies on the intuition that at a maximum, $f(x,y)$ cannot be increasing in the direction of any such neighboring point that also has $g(x,y)=c$. If it were, we could walk along $g(x,y)=c$ to get higher, meaning that the starting point wasn't actually the maximum. Viewed in this way, it is an exact analogue to testing if the derivative of an unconstrained function is $0$, that is, we are verifying that the directional derivative is $0$ in any relevant (viable) direction."

Note that the equations of the Lagrange Multiplier method are *necessary but not sufficient* conditions for an optimum (on a boundaryless domain). If they have multiple solutions, you will have to compare the solutions further and/or examine their Hessians.